# Getting files by using Prefixfilefilter and suffixfilefilter in java

Tags: java

I have one folder which contains some files.  I want all the files that starts with prefix 'Rz'  and suffix . lst.  . so for ex RzCountry. Lst . so I want Country ..  So how can i do that

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: I have tried by using filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an exemple of what you need :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// replace here by your directory path
File dir = new File("directory_path");

String prefixe = "Rz";
String sufixe = "ls";

// retrieve all the file with name containing Rz at the beginning and ends with ls
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileName -> 
                  fileName.getName().startsWith(prefixe) && 
                  fileName.getName().endsWith(sufixe));

// if you need to have all the name of the file without prefixe/sufixe
List<String> list = Stream.of(files)
                          .map(file -> 
                               file.getName().substring(prefixe.length(), 
                                                        file.getName().length() - sufixe.length()))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me  . It is taking whole path in an array .. I just want Country to display.

Comment: Hello, you have to replace directory_path by the path of the folder wich contains the files you want to retrieve, and you can use this line to print all the values : list.forEach(System.out::println);